# Error when I try to use textFile in sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I was trying to follow the tutorial to get wordcount of the "README.md" by using sparkR.
Spark version: 1.6.1
R version: 3.3.0
Ubuntu version: 14
However, when I do `lines <- sc.textFile("README.md")`, I got error here

```
Error: could not find function "sc.textFile"
```

Then, I tried `lines <- SparkR:::textFile(sc, "./README.md")` instead, I got this error:

```
16/07/01 00:06:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 88.5 KB, free 258.9 KB)
16/07/01 00:06:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 19.6 KB, free 278.5 KB)
16/07/01 00:06:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on localhost:40985 (size: 19.6 KB, free: 511.5 MB)
16/07/01 00:06:26 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 4 from textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
16/07/01 00:06:26 ERROR RBackendHandler: collect on 44 failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
  java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.proto
16/07/01 00:15:59 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on localhost:40985 in memory (size: 14.1 KB, free: 511.5 MB)
```

What's more, I tried to do the same thing in PySpark shell, still, it didn't work as tutorial.

```
>>> lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
16/07/01 00:27:22 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 227.6 KB, free 506.2 KB)
16/07/01 00:27:22 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 19.6 KB, free 525.8 KB)
16/07/01 00:27:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on localhost:33186 (size: 19.6 KB, free: 511.4 MB)
16/07/01 00:27:22 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
>>> lines.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1004, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 995, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 869, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:706)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1439)
    ... 56 more
```

Does sparkR stop supporting textFile function? Or is my JAVA_HOME setting wrong(though I am able to get correct response by `java -version`)?

Another tiny problem is that I have to initialize SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME before I imported sparkR package, like this:

```
if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
  Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/usr/local/spark")
}
if (nchar(Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")) < 1) {
  Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64")
}
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local", appName = "test", sparkHome = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
lines <- sc.textFile("README.md")
```

If I don't, I would get errors when I do `library(sparkR)`.
Do I have to do this? It isn't required in most of the tutorials online.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I appears like problem with hdfs build try this `lines = sc.textFile("file:///<localpathto>/README.md")` and let us know it works or not?

Comment: Excellent!! It works when I follow what @WoodChopper said above!Thank you so much! My root dictionary of spark is /usr/local/spark, so I tried `lines = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/README.md")`, then it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is hdfs is not running or problem with installation, your spark build by default looks into hdfs path,

for example when you provide,

```
lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

it will be converted to,

```
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://ip:port/README.md")
```

so error for you should be `fileNotFound` since your hdfs is not running/issue it is throwing  connection refused error.

Try this to get your hdfs running if required,

```
cd HADDOP_HOME/sbin
./stop-all.sh
./start-all.sh
```